# subfloat - enclose a set of subfloats in a subfloat environment

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am struggling in finding the correct implementation for putting my two rows of figures inside a subfloat environment. What I have now is the following:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{.png}
        \label{fig1}
    }
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{.png}
        \label{fig:2}
    }   
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{.png}
        \label{fig:3}
    }

    \subfloat[ ]{
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{.png}
        \label{fig:4}
    }
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{.png}
        \label{fig:5}
    }   
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{.png}
        \label{fig:6}
    }

    \caption{}
    \label{fig:whatever}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

It returns the following output:
[image: output]

I would like to have one more level of subcaption on the row. I imagine refering each single picture in the following format: Figure 1.a.1. I tried putting them in a subfloat too, but latex returns an error on the stack. One constraint, I am forced to use the subfig package, I cannot move either to subfigure or subcaption.

EDIT: example:
[image: example]

Comment: It is hard to make a figure. Basically I would like to have a,b,c grouped in a figure. There should be like a figure caption below each row

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni Readers will be confused, especially when you refer to any of these subsubfigures. I think you really should place each of (a) and (b) to a new figure.

Comment: The problem arises because these figures are going to have the same caption

Comment: [Multiple Figure Numbering and Multiple Captions for Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355109/multiple-figure-numbering-and-multiple-captions-for-figures/355475) might be useful.

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah the solution is using `subcaption`, that I cannot use. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a duplicate of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423580/how-to-label-subset-of-figures-as-subfigures-and-include-an-overall-caption/423634?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C5.2462#423634) only using `\subfloat` (more or less) from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481768/compatibility-of-subfigure-with-subfig-package/481921#481921).

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionSubType{subfigure}
\captionsetup[subsubfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubfigure}{\arabic{subsubfigure}}
\AtBeginDocument{% trial and error
  \let\oldsubsubfigure=\subsubfigure
  \renewcommand{\subsubfigure}{\expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{subfigure}%
    \oldsubsubfigure}%
}

\newsavebox{\subsubfloatbox}% probably overkill
\newcommand{\subsubfloat}[2][\empty]% #1 = caption (optional), #2 = image
{\bgroup
  \captionsetup[subsubfigure]{font=footnotesize}%
  \savebox\subsubfloatbox{#2}%
  \begin{subsubfigure}[t]{\wd\subsubfloatbox}
    \usebox\subsubfloatbox
    \ifx\empty#1\relax
      \stepcounter{subsubfigure}%
    \else
      \caption{#1}%
    \fi
  \end{subsubfigure}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \subsubfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image}%
        \label{fig1}%
     }\hfil
    \subsubfloat[\label{fig:2}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\hfil
    \subsubfloat[\label{fig:3}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\par
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
    \subsubfloat[\label{fig:4}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\hfil
    \subsubfloat[\label{fig:5}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\hfil
    \subsubfloat[\label{fig:6}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:whatever}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]